# Terraform, How to output multiple private ips

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I use "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws" to provision two ec2 instances. How to output these two private IPs?

```
module "ec2_jekins_agent" {
    source = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"
    version  = "4.1.4"
    for_each = toset(["one", "two"])
    name = "jenkins-agent-${each.key}"
    vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.sg_jenkins_agent.id]
    subnet_id = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.private_subnets[0]
}
```

The code below does not work.

```
output "jenkins_agent_private_ips" {
  value = [module.ec2_jekins_agent.private_ip]
}
```

Error: Unsupported attribute
module.ec2_jekins_agent is object with 2 attributes
This object does not have an attribute named "private_ip".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've used `for_each`, you can use [values](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/values):

```
output "jenkins_agent_private_ips" {
  value = values(module.ec2_jekins_agent)[*].private_ip
}
```